# Violin plots over multiple normalised variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, normalization, violin-plot

I am trying to plot multiple samples over multiple compounds using the violin plot after normalisation of the dataset. I have a data set with different samples but with same compounds. I will try to simulate my problem:

#Creation of data set

```
DF1 <- 
  data.frame(Sample.Name = 
               
               c("A1_VAR_B", "A2_VAR_B", "A3_VAR_B", "A4_VAR_B", "A5_VAR_B", 
                 "A6_VAR_B","B1_VAR_B", "B2_VAR_B", "B3_VAR_B", "B4_VAR_B", 
                 "B5_VAR_B", "B6_VAR_B"),
             Compound1 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound2 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound3 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound4 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound5 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound6 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound7 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound8 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound9 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound10 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound11 = runif(12,0,100),
             Compound12 = runif(12,0,100))
```

Now I try my first normalisation method

```
Normalization_MM <- function(x) {
  (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
}

Data_normalized_TEST <- as.data.frame(lapply(DF1[2:12], Normalization_MM))

Data_normalized_TEST$Sample.Name <- DF1$Sample.Name
Data_normalized_TEST <- Data_normalized_TEST %>%
  relocate(Sample.Name, .before = Compound1)
```

I aim to test various normalisation methods and plot them to see how to change with each normalisation function/method.

```
TESTT2 <- Data_normalized_TEST %>%
  gather(Metabolites, Values, -Sample.Name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Metabolites, Values)) +
  geom_violin(adjust = .5)
```

The outcome is no plots at all after normalisation. Whereas before the normalisation, I can get decent plots. And I would also like to keep sample names and compound names in the plot. I appreciate the help ! Please provide me with feedback if my explanation or illustration was lacking in some way, so I can explain more if necessary.

**EDIT**
After removing the slice function, the plots became more clear. However, implementing this on a dataset bigger than 30 compounds does not work. I don't see any plots at all. How can I solve for this?

Comment: What are you intending with this line. `slice(rep(row_number(), Values)) %>%`? I'm guessing it's meant to be a weighting of some sort, but it's not clear to me why that would be necessary, and it will work differently when it has numbers > 1 (like originally) vs. < 1 (like after normalization). R can't make 0.25765 copies of a row...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @JonSpring. I agree with you. After removal, it did a better job however not working with a bigger dataset. Is there any way we can solve for that?